# Record type to temporary variable

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to store record to temporary variable and pass it through function?

If I have two records like:

```
TMyRec1 = packed record
  SomeValue : Integer;
end;

TMyRec2 = packed record
  ThisIsMessage : String;
end;
```

And now I want to be able to do something like this:

```
function GetRec(recId: Integer) : Variant;
begin
  case (recId) of
    1 : Result := TMyRec1.Create();
    2 : Result := TMyRec2.Create();
    //... many
  else
    
  end;
end;
```

And also to return it back to original type like:

```
function GetRec1(rec: Variant) : TMyRec1;
begin
  Result := TMyRec1(rec);
  // here I do lots of default things with this record type
end;

function GetRec2(rec: Variant) : TMyRec2;
begin
  Result := TMyRec2(rec);
  // here I do lots of default things with this record type
end;
```

Finally an complete function should be able to do the following:

```
procedure MainFunction();
var myRec : Variant; //I want to avoid to specify each T here
begin
  myRec := GetRec(1);
  PrintRec1(GetRec1(myRec));

  myRec := GetRec(2);
  PrintRec2(GetRec2(myRec));
end;

procedure PrintRec1(rec: TMyRec1);
begin
  Print(IntToStr(rec.SomeValue));
end;

procedure PrintRec2(rec: TMyRec2);
begin
  Print(rec.ThisIsMessage);
end;
```

I have tried with Variant, TObject, NativeUInt casting but nothing seem to work.

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT**

```
TMyRec = record
end;

TMyRec1 = TMyRec
  SomeValue : Integer;
end;

TMyRec2 = TMyRec
  ThisIsMessage : String;
end;
```

Can be done something like this?

I don't need safety checking and rising exceptions I will take care of that to make sure I pass correct one where required.

Comment: You could try function overloading!

Comment: @DelphiCoder but then if I have 100 record types and add a new one I need to add also new overload function and copy 5+ lines of code in each of those functions

Comment: Seems like you want something like C# boxing/unboxing. Do you really use Delphi 7? That's pretty constraining.

Comment: Maybe records are not the way to move on but rather classes? But then you have the additional complexity of creating and freeing them. The later could be circumvented by also using interfaces...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I use Delphi 7 just because of some old implementation which maybe I could adjust for newer version but I am too lazy to switch to new. I will try.

Comment: @DelphiCoder Yes well I need to solve it with records not classes.

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you are presenting us with an XY problem. Google it. You've not told us the actual problem. But you've asked how to implement your chosen solution to the problem. Thing is, your solution isn't practical. We can answer the question, but we can't help solve the problem. Because you didn't state the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `record` does not have a `Create()` constructor by default, like a `class` does, so `TMyRec1.Create()` and `TMyRec2.Create()` will not work as shown.

But, in Delphi 2006 and later, you can manually add a static `Create()` method that returns a new `record` instance (several of Delphi's own native RTL records do this, such as `TFormatSettings`, `TRttiContext`, etc), eg:

```pascal
TMyRec1 = packed record
  SomeValue : Integer;
  class function Create: TMyRec1; static;
end;

TMyRec2 = packed record
  ThisIsMessage : String;
  class function Create: TMyRec2; static;
end;

...

class function TMyRec1.Create: TMyRec1;
begin
  Result.SomeValue := ...;
end;

class function TMyRec2.Create: TMyRec2;
begin
  Result.ThisIsMessage := ...;
end;
```

Otherwise, for earlier versions, you will have to use standalone functions, eg:

```pascal
TMyRec1 = packed record
  SomeValue : Integer;
end;

TMyRec2 = packed record
  ThisIsMessage : String;
end;

function CreateRec1: TMyRec1;
function CreateRec2: TMyRec2;

...

function CreateRec1: TMyRec1;
begin
  Result.SomeValue := ...;
end;

function CreateRec2: TMyRec2;
begin
  Result.ThisIsMessage := ...;
end;
```

But, either way, know that by default you can't just store arbitrary `record` types in a `Variant`, it doesn't know how to store and retrieve them.  You have to teach it how to do that. You do that by deriving a class from [`TCustomVariantType`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.TCustomVariantType) and override its various operational methods for casting, comparing, etc, and then register that class with the RTL so that the `Variant` infrastructure knows about it. See [Defining Custom Variants](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Defining_Custom_Variants_Index) in Delphi's documentation for more details about that. Only then will your `GetRec()`, `GetRec1()`, and `GetRec2()` functions be able to work exactly as you have coded them.

Otherwise, consider an alternative approach, for instance defining a custom [tagged record](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Variant_Parts_in_Records), similar to how `Variant` works internally, eg:

```pascal
PMyRec1 = ^TMyRec1;
TMyRec1 = packed record
  SomeValue : Integer;
end;

PMyRec2 = ^TMyRec2;
TMyRec2 = packed record
  ThisIsMessage : String;
end;

TMyRec = record
  case Tag: Integer of
    1 : (Rec1: PMyRec1);
    2 : (Rec2: PMyRec2);
    ...
end;

function GetRec(recId: Integer) : TMyRec;
begin
  Result.Tag := recId;
  case recId of
    1 : New(Result.Rec1);
    2 : New(Result.Rec2);
    ...
  else
    raise ...;    
  end;
end;

function DisposeRec(var rec: TMyRec);
begin
  case rec.Tag of
    1 : Dispose(rec.Rec1);
    2 : Dispose(rec.Rec2);
    ...
  end;
  rec.Tag := 0;
end;

function GetRec1(var rec: TMyRec) : TMyRec1;
begin
  if rec.Tag <> 1 then raise ...;
  Result := rec.Rec1^;
  // here I do lots of default things with this record type
end;

function GetRec2(var rec: TMyRec) : TMyRec2;
begin
  if rec.Tag <> 2 then raise ...;
  Result := rec.Rec2^;
  // here I do lots of default things with this record type
end;

procedure MainFunction;
var
  myRec : TMyRec;
begin
  myRec := GetRec(1);
  try
    PrintRec1(GetRec1(myRec));
  finally
    DisposeRec(myRec);
  end;

  myRec := GetRec(2);
  try
    PrintRec2(GetRec2(myRec));
  finally
    DisposeRec(myRec);
  end;
end;

procedure PrintRec1(const rec: TMyRec1);
begin
  Print(IntToStr(rec.SomeValue));
end;

procedure PrintRec2(const rec: TMyRec2);
begin
  Print(rec.ThisIsMessage);
end;
```

Comment: "A record does not have a Create() constructor, like a class does." Well, you can define a `constructor` on a record type, as long as it does have at least a single parameter (for some reason, parameterless constructors are not allowed on record types).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*for some reason, parameterless constructors are not allowed on record types*" - that is covered in the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Records_.28advanced.29): "*Records are constructed automatically, using a default no-argument constructor, but classes must be explicitly constructed. Because records have a default no-argument constructor, any user-defined record constructor must have one or more parameters.*"

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I cannot put case inside of record? Anyway again I have to define each separately. Cant I just make some base type which all of them derive from and use that one?

Comment: I don't actually need comparing and other stuff I just want to put an record to object or whatever pass it to a function that accepts anything and then from that function pass it to another function which know exactly what type of record. Let it on me to make sure the correct record is passed from unknown object!

Comment: @RemyLebeau It work yes but there is one extra end; for TMyRec however please check last part of my edit on question

Comment: Also I wonder why is "PMyRec1 = ^TMyRec1;" required? Why I cant just use in the case of TMyRec directly TMyRec1?

Comment: @RemyLebeau According to question tags this question is for Delphi 7

Comment: @SecretaryOfEducation records have no inheritance! You need to use classes instead.

Comment: @SecretaryOfEducation "*I cannot put case inside of record*" - [yes, you can](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Variant_Parts_in_Records). "*Cant I just make some base type which all of them derive from and use that one?*" - not with records, no. Use classes instead. "*there is one extra `end;` for `TMyRec`*" - fixed.

Comment: @SecretaryOfEducation "*why is `PMyRec1` required?*" - because your records contain compiler-managed types in them, and those types can't be used directly in tagged records, per the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Variant_Parts_in_Records): "*The types must not be long strings, dynamic arrays, variants (that is, Variant types), or interfaces, nor can they be structured types that contain long strings, dynamic arrays, variants, or interfaces; but they can be pointers to these types.*"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "*this question is for Delphi 7*" - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help I think this solves the question asked, however I think I will have to update to new version at the end.